# Why does constexpr context make the compiler fail, while w/o it optimizes perfectly?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization, clang++, c++20

I played around with `constexpr` and realized some interesting behavior:

- In some situations adding `constexpr` in front of a function enables *GCC* to try optimizing harder which results in fully optimizing the function away and just providing the calculated value.
- However, calling such a fully optimized function from a `constexpr` context results in errors because it internally uses (compiler-built-in) functions/intrinsics which are not marked `constexpr` (in particularly `memcpy`).
- (*Clang* fails directly when applying `constexpr` to such a function, even without a `constexpr` context.)

**Why is that so?**

- Shouldn't the compiler (*GCC*) be able to still optimize, even in `constexpr` context?
- C++ proposal [P0202](https://wg21.link/p0202) (which made it into C++20) wanted to make functions like `memcpy` `constexpr` (see section **III.B** in [original revision](https://wg21.link/p0202r0)), but that was rejected and changed because compiler-built-in versions of such functions would achieve the same (see section **III.A** in [latest revision](https://wg21.link/p0202)).
- So, are *GCC* and *Clang* wrong in not allowing `memcpy` in `constexpr` functions/context? (Note: `memcpy` and `__builtin_memcpy` are equivalent.)

---

**As examples are easier to understand, here is such an example.**
(You can even see it more comfortably with its results in *Compiler Explorer* [here](https://godbolt.org/z/m9ant9).)

**Note:** I was unable to come up with a simple example where simply adding `constexpr` to the function helped the *GCC* optimizer to fully optimize, which it otherwise would not. But believe me, that I have such examples, which are more complicated (and sadly closed-source).

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

constexpr std::uint32_t extract(const std::uint8_t* data) noexcept
{
    std::uint32_t num;
    memcpy(&num, data, sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> a1 {{ 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff }};
    /*constexpr*/ auto val = extract(a1.data());  // <--- Using constexpr here makes compiler fail.
    return val;
}
```

*GCC* is able to optimize this to just:

```
main:     # @main
    mov   eax, -1
    ret
```

*Clang* can optimize it too, if removing the `constexpr` in front of the function definition.

However, if commenting in the `constexpr` in front of the function call (and thereby calling the function from `constexpr` context) the compiler fails with something like this:

GCC:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:15:33:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'extract(a1.std::array<unsigned char, 4>::data())'
<source>:8:11: error: 'memcpy(((void*)(& num)), ((const void*)(& a1.std::array<unsigned char, 4>::_M_elems)), 4)' is not a constant expression
    8 |     memcpy(&num, data, sizeof(std::uint32_t));
      |     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Clang:

```
<source>:5:25: error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
constexpr std::uint32_t extract(const std::uint8_t* data) noexcept
                        ^
<source>:8:5: note: non-constexpr function 'memcpy' cannot be used in a constant expression
    memcpy(&num, data, sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    ^
<source>:15:20: error: constexpr variable 'val' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr auto val = extract(a1.data());  // <--- Error!
                   ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:5: note: non-constexpr function 'memcpy' cannot be used in a constant expression
    memcpy(&num, data, sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    ^
<source>:15:26: note: in call to 'extract(&a1._M_elems[0])'
    constexpr auto val = extract(a1.data());  // <--- Error!

                         ^
2 errors generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: *"For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (8.20), or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object (6.6.2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required."*

Comment: OP: What happens if instead of marking these functions `constexpr`, you just marked them `inline`? Does that also trigger the more aggressive optimization mode?

Comment: @Brian: That is a really good question. And it seems the optimization hint for *GCC* just comes from `constexpr` being implicitly `inline`.

Comment: Interestingly, replacing `memcpy` with `__builtin_memcpy` satisfies *Clang*, too, as long as it is not called from a `constexpr` context.

So, I assume using `inline` in such situations is the correct thing to do!?

Comment: This is the associated feature-request to GCC to support `__builtin_memcpy` in `constexpr` context: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94082

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [dcl.constexpr](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6)

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression, or, for a constructor, an evaluated subexpression of the initialization full-expression of some constant-initialized object ([basic.start.static]), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

As [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) is not `constexpr`, your program is ill formed NDR.

Using the function in `contsexpr` context would allow to have diagnostic.

> In some situations adding `constexpr` in front of a function enables GCC to try optimizing harder which results in fully optimizing the function away and just providing the calculated value.

It is a good hint (as `inline` before).

`constexpr` function can be "misused":

```
constexpr std::size_t factorial(std::size_t n) {/*..*/}

int main()
{
    std::cout << factorial(5); // computed at runtime (but probably optimized)
}
```

Correct way would be

```
int main()
{
    constexpr auto fact5 = factorial(5); // computed at compile time
    std::cout << fact5; 
}
```

Comment: "As `memcpy` is not `constexpr`, your program is ill formed NDR."
- Same is true for `__builtin_memcpy` and `__builtin_bswap32` (I assume). Interestingly, `__builtin_bswap32` can be used just fine in `constexpr` context.